# the site can't be reached while doing file uploading

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I am new and I don't know where is the mistake, I think I have taken care the routes and all but still I am not sure. Please help me out.

So when I do `localhost:8000/uploadfile/` it gives me this error

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
>   Try:
>   Checking the connection
>   Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And when I go through the detail URL it gives me:

> the view[uploadfile] not found

This is my form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>
    
    <?php
        echo Form::open(array('url'=>'/uploadfile','files'->'true'));
        echo 'Select the file to upload';
        echo Form::file('image');
        echo Form::submit('upload file');
        echo Form::close();
    
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller is:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\files;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class UploadFileController extends Controller {
        public function index() {
            return view('uploadfile');
        }
        public function showUploadFile(Request $request) {
            $file = $request->file('image');

            //Display File Name
            echo 'File Name: '.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            echo '<br>';

            //Display File Extension
            echo 'File Extension: '.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            echo '<br>';

            //Display File Real Path
            echo 'File Real Path: '.$file->getRealPath();
            echo '<br>';

            //Display File Size
            echo 'File Size: '.$file->getSize();
            echo '<br>';

            //Display File Mime Type
            echo 'File Mime Type: '.$file->getMimeType();

            //Move Uploaded File
            $destinationPath = 'uploads';
            $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }
```

Finally my route:

```
Route::get('/uploadfile','UploadFileController@index');
Route::post('/uploadfile','UploadFileController@showUploadFile');
```

Comment: your view file name is `uploadfile`

Comment: Is server running?

Comment: yes my server is running

Comment: Do you reach a webpage ? Did you open the 8000 port on the firewall of your server ?

Comment: I fixed that but now i have this error  ' ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class view does not exist'

Comment: You should not `echo` anything out inside a controller nor in a HTML file. Stick to MVC principle Laravel provides and pass your variables to the view and use Blade to print them to the screen. 
Your form code contains also another error `'files'->'true'` should be `'files' => 'true'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

your view file like:

**Path**:

**`yourproject folder/resources/views/uploadfile.blade.php`**

```
<form class="form-bordered" action="{{url('/uploadfile')}}" method="POST">
   <div>
       <lable>Select the file to upload</lable>
       <input type="file" name="image">
       <input type="submit" value="upload file">


   </div>

</form>
```